# Slide Toggle on link click, but keep link clickable to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a "dot" navigation on a site that has one link with a submenu. Originally, I had a simple JQ function that would slideToggle() the submenu *on hover* but that was causing some 'bouncing' issues. So, I reverted it back to click() function.

```
$("#troy-dot-nav li.menu-item-81 > a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('800');
});
```

In doing so, I need to add the preventDefault() so the submenu would open up on click, but disable the link.

Turns out, I need to keep the link on that active to navigate to that top-level page, but can't seem to figure out the best way to go about allowing the submenu to open (on click or hover; without bouncing) and keep the menu link active.

HTML for Menu

```
<div class="menu-primary-container">
  <ul id="troy-dot-nav" class="menu reverse-dots">
      <li class="..."><a href="...">About</a></li>
      <li class="... menu-item-81">
          <a href="...">Integrated Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
              <li class="..."><a href="...">EPC &amp; Project Services</a></li>
              <li class="..."><a href="...">Pipeline Construction</a></li>
              <li class="..."><a href="...">Facility Construction</a></li>
              <li class="..."><a href="...">Integrity Management</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="..."><a href="...">Safety &amp; Quality</a></li>
      <li class="..."><a href="...">Careers</a></li>
      <li class="..."><a href="...">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS creates the dots on the li:after. Removed extra HTML for cleaner look here.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use css to add/remove an active class and also close all / open related submenu ?

Like so :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').click(function() {
    // Remove the "active" class from all links
    $('.link').removeClass('active');

    // Add the "active" class to the clicked link
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // Find the corresponding sublist
    var sublistId = $(this).data('sublist');
    var sublist = $('#' + sublistId);

    // Close all sublists
    $('.sublist').hide();

    // Open the corresponding sublist
    sublist.show();
  });
});
```

with that kind of html :

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link" data-sublist="sublist-1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link" data-sublist="sublist-2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link" data-sublist="sublist-3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sublist-1" class="sublist">
  <li>Sublist item 1</li>
  <li>Sublist item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sublist-2" class="sublist">
  <li>Sublist item 3</li>
  <li>Sublist item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sublist-3" class="sublist">
  <li>Sublist item 5</li>
  <li>Sublist item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need to remove the preventDefault() so the user can click that link, but need to have a way for the submenu to open too. That's my problem. That's why I had hover() vs click() the first time, but that was causing a bouncing issue when hovering in and out of the link

Comment: can you edit the question and use a sandbox so i can check what is the behavior linked to the click and your submenu issue?

Comment: is the submenu opened with a jQuery event or function ? If yes, you could simply trigger the opening of the link's submenu in the function i posted ?

Comment: the submenu opens when the parent link is clicked, this opens the nested ul submenu.

Comment: I guess you should close sumbenus / open the related submenus. I will edit this answer to show you a better organized code for the behaviour your want to achieve

Comment: did you finally fix your issue @SalB ?